# Отцентровать по высоте текст кнопки. CSS

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Нужно сделать кнопку из тега **a**. **button** мне не подойдет. Столкнулся вот с какой проблемой... Кнопка имеет задний фон с шириной и высотой, проблема в том что из-за высоты текст смещается вверх, а нужно чтобы он был по центру.

Прочитал много статей на тему выравнивания по вертикали, но мне не помог ни один из предложенных там способов, поэтому я тут. Как сделать текст по центру?

Вот код:

```
<a class="button main__button" target="_blank" href="http://culture.ru/">афиша мероприятий</a>

.button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.main__button {
    width: 340px;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 29px;
    letter-spacing: -0.005em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #001185;
    background: #FA8E5A;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 35px 0 40px;
    border: 3px solid #FA8E5A;
}
```

[image: кнопка]

Comment: line-height 70px а не 29px

Comment: и display: block ещё надо

Comment: Пример: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OJPKOqE

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо! все работает)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы добавил свойство:

```
.main__button {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: center;
 text-align: center;
}
```